# Is it possible to use handlebars inside handlebars path?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, mustache

I have an object like this:

`{
    "var1": "x",
    "var2": {
        "x":
        "y":
        "z":
    }
}`

I want something like `{{var2.{{var1}} }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lookup built-in helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) (Under "The lookup helper" section) can handle this.

```js
var obj =  {
  "var1": "z",
  "var2":
  {
    "x": 'x value',
    "y": 'y value',
    "z": 'z value'
  }
}
var output =  Handlebars.compile('{{lookup var2 var1}}')(obj)
// output would be 'z value' in this case
```

It basically allows you to "lookup" property (`var1`) in object (`var2`)